# Jest not working with react-redux connect component in React JS

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, babel-jest

I am using redux for my app and trying to create test cases with jest but my component showing null or i can't update my states from the test component.

Here is my code:

**My Component:**

```
class AddNonGeEquipment extends Component {
...
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddNonGeEquipment);
```

**My Test Component:**

```
    import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
    import React from 'react';
    import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
    import AddNonGeEquipment from './AddNonGeEquipment';
    import sinon from 'sinon';
    import { TextField } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
    import { Router } from 'react-router';
    import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import { emptyReducerMock, initialReducerMock } from '../../testing/mocks/reducer.mock';
    import ReactTestUtils, { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
    import { withContext } from "shallow-with-context";
    
    describe('App Componet', () => {
      let component;
      let store;
      let mockState;
      const mockStore = configureStore([]);
      const history = createMemoryHistory();
      const props = { 
      updateFieldValue: jest.fn(),
      updateError: jest.fn(),
      saveSystem: jest.fn(),
      configureSystemView: jest.fn(),
      systemIdValidation: jest.fn(),
      resetDetails: jest.fn(),
      deleteSystem: jest.fn(),
      saveSystemFailure: jest.fn(),
      deleteSystemFailure: jest.fn()
      }
      beforeEach(() => {
        store = mockStore(initialReducerMock);
        component = mount(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={history}>
              <AddNonGeEquipment history={history} {...props} />
            </Router>
          </Provider>
        );
        mockState = {
          store: true
        }
  });
it('mock', async () => {
// const myComponent = shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />);
    // myComponent.setState({ ...mockState });
    // const instance = myComponent.instance();
    // expect(instance.state).toEqual(mockState);
    // store = mockStore(initialReducerMock);
    
    // component.setState({ ...mockState });
    // const instance = component.instance();
    // //expect(instance.state).toEqual(mockState);
    // console.log("MY COMPONENT instance",instance)

    store = mockStore(initialReducerMock);

    // const wrapper = shallow(<Provider store={store}>
    //   <Router history={history}>
    //     <AddNonGeEquipment history={history} {...props}/>
    //   </Router>
    // </Provider>);
    // const storyApp = wrapper.find();

    const loginComponent = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <AddNonGeEquipment history={history} {...props}/>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
    
    //loginComponent.setState({ show: true });
    const contextFunctionMock = jest.fn();
    const context = { contextFunction: contextFunctionMock };
    const MyComponentWithContext = withContext(AddNonGeEquipment, context);
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponentWithContext />, { context });
    await wrapper.instance().onPressButton();
    expect(contextFunctionMock).toHaveBeenCalled();

    //console.log("loginComponent",loginComponent);
    // loginComponent.find(DeleteModal).prop('show')(true);
    // expect(result).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

Errors:

1. When i am not using  getting below error Could not find
   "store" in the context of "Connect(AddNonGeEquipment)". Either wrap
   the root component in a , or pass a custom React context
   provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer
   to Connect(AddNonGeEquipment) in connect options.
2. When removed connect from class component getting propos undefined
   error
3. When calling directly component getting below error Cannot read
   property 'find' of undefined

Anyone having solution for the same please share.